# How to disable a key on key press on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This how the code works, when i press left key button (e.keyCode =39) it jumps up to the next page. All in all there are 7 ($('#btn-group input').length)  pages in my program. I tried using preventDefault(); command inside the condition where the comment i dont know hat will put here but i wont work on my program( it jumps to page 8 and returns to page 7). Thank you

```js
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == '39') {

    var old_num = $('#btn-group').find('.active-btn').val();
    var new_num = +old_num + 1;

    $('#page' + old_num).toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left',
      complete: function() {
        $('#btn_page' + old_num).removeClass('active-btn');
        $('#page' + old_num).clearQueue();
        $('#page' + old_num).removeClass('active-page');

        $('#page' + new_num).addClass('active-page');
        $('#btn_page' + new_num).addClass('active-btn');

        if (new_num == $('#btn-group input').length) {
          // i dont know what will put here
        }

        $('#page' + new_num).toggle('slide', {
          direction: 'right'
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right" id="btn_all">
 <input  class="btn active-btn" type="button" id="prev_btn"  style="background-color:#66cdaa" style="width:70px;margin:1em"  value="Prev.">
 <div class="btn-group" id="btn-group">
 <br>
<input  class="btn butt active-btn" type="button" id="btn_page1" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="1">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page2" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="2">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page3" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="3">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page4" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="4">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page5" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="5">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page6" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="6">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page7" style ="background-color:#66cdaa" value="7">
<input  class="btn butt active-btn" type="button"  style ="background-color:#66cdaa" id="next_btn" value="Next">
</div>
```

Comment: what is the use of the code snippet ?

Comment: post your HTML.

Comment: Try `document.onkeypress = checkKey;` instead

Comment: Use `return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault()`;

Comment: you need to check for the length _before_ you fire the `toggle`, and `return` if it returns a bad length

Comment: i changed it but the code wont work @Jackson

Comment: i tried return false but the same error occues @Ionut

Comment: i tried a number but it still the same @haxxxton

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez, please add a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net. Now it does not seem to do anything when I press the key you mentioned. No errors also. Also, 39 is the code for the right arrow, not the left one. And what is the `#page*` element? As I said, please provide a full working snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: They were two separate snippets. I merged them into one snippet, but still, it doesn't work and outputs script errors.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the functionality properly, but it seems that you are sliding the page to the left, then in the callback you are sliding it back to the right. I imagine this would cause it to turn to page 8 and then back to page 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function on keypress of an element.

```
function ValidateClientname(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        alert (charCode); // this will give you key value and you can pass it in if statement like  if ((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode ==8))
        if ((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "short circuit" your function before it reaches the `.toggle` function. This will prevent all further execution of the function.

```js
$(function() {

  document.onkeydown = checkKey;

  function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '39') {

      var old_num = $('#btn-group').find('.active-btn').val();
      var new_num = +old_num + 1;
      
      // if new number is for a page that doesnt exist
      // short circuit
      if (new_num == $('#btn-group input').length) {
          return false;
      }

      $('#page' + old_num).toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left',
        complete: function() {
          $('#btn_page' + old_num).removeClass('active-btn');
          $('#page' + old_num).removeClass('active-page');

          $('#page' + new_num).addClass('active-page');
          $('#btn_page' + new_num).addClass('active-btn');

          $('#page' + new_num).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active-btn {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="pull-right" id="btn_all">
  <input class="btn active-btn" type="button" id="prev_btn" style="background-color:#66cdaa" style="width:70px;margin:1em" value="Prev.">
  <div class="btn-group" id="btn-group">
    <input class="btn butt active-btn" type="button" id="btn_page1" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="1" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page2" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="2" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page3" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="3" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page4" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="4" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page5" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="5" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page6" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="6" />
    <input class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page7" style="background-color:#66cdaa" value="7" />
    <input class="btn butt active-btn" type="button" style="background-color:#66cdaa" id="next_btn" value="Next" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pages_all">
  <div id="page1" class="page active-page" style="display:block">Page 1</div>
  <div id="page2" class="page">Page 2</div>
  <div id="page3" class="page">Page 3</div>
  <div id="page4" class="page">Page 4</div>
  <div id="page5" class="page">Page 5</div>
  <div id="page6" class="page">Page 6</div>
  <div id="page7" class="page">Page 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still produces a sh*tload of errors, and the left arrow doesn't work

Comment: @JeremyThille, the OP said that he uses left arrow, but in his code he uses the key code for the right arrow.

Comment: @JeremyThille i see no errors when i run the snippet. Could you elaborate please

Comment: The errors are gone now. I used to see a console underneath the snippet, with a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active-btn').siblings().removeClass('active-btn');
});
document.onkeydown = checkKey;


function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  var old_num = parseInt($('#btn-group').find('.active-btn').val());
  var new_num = old_num+1;
  if (new_num == $('#btn-group input').length) {
      new_num=1;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    $('#page' + old_num).toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'left',
        complete: function() {
        $('#btn_page' + old_num).removeClass('active-btn');
        $('#page' + old_num).clearQueue();
        $('#page' + old_num).removeClass('active-page');
        $('#page' + new_num).addClass('active-page');
        $('#btn_page' + new_num).addClass('active-btn');
        
        $('#page' + new_num).toggle('slide', {
          direction: 'right'
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.pager:not(:first-child) { display:none;}

.butt{background-color:#66cdaa}
.active-btn {background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p id="page1" class="pager" style="display:inline-block">1</p>
<p id="page2" class="pager">2</p>
<p id="page3" class="pager">3</p>
<p id="page4" class="pager">4</p>
<p id="page5" class="pager">5</p>
<p id="page6" class="pager">6</p>
<p id="page7" class="pager">7</p>
<div class="pull-right" id="btn_all">
 <input  class="btn active-btn" type="button" id="prev_btn"  style="background-color:#66cdaa" style="width:70px;margin:1em"  value="Prev.">
 <div class="btn-group" id="btn-group">
 <br>
<input  class="btn butt active-btn" type="button" id="btn_page1" value="1">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page2"  value="2">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page3"  value="3">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page4"  value="4">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page5"  value="5">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page6" value="6">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button" id="btn_page7"  value="7">
<input  class="btn butt" type="button"   id="next_btn" value="Next">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a `switch` statement to test for the key :

```
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37 :
            prevPage(); break;
        case 39 :
            nextPage(); break;
    }
}
```

I have written my own version of what you're trying to do (at least what I think you're trying to do), feel free to use that as an inspiration.
I use CSS3 transitions instead of jQuery's toggle.

```js
const pagesCount = 7;
let currentPage = 1;

// ---- Generating buttons and pages
const $btnGroup = $("#btn-group");
const $pagesContainer = $("#pages");
for(let i=1; i<=pagesCount; i++){
 $pagesContainer.append(`<div class='page'><h2>PAGE ${i}</h2></div>`);
 $btnGroup.append(`<input type='button' value='${i}'/>`);
}
const $btns = $btnGroup.find("input")
$btns.first().addClass("active");
const $pages = $(".page");
$pages.not(":eq(0)").addClass("toRight");
// ---- End generating buttons

$btns.click( function() {
 currentPage = +$(this).val();
 changePage(currentPage);
});

changePage = (pageNum) => {
 $pages.removeClass("toLeft toRight");
 $pages.slice(0, pageNum-1).addClass("toLeft");
 $pages.slice(pageNum, pagesCount).addClass("toRight");
 updateButtons();
}

updateButtons = () => {
 $btns.removeClass("active");
 $btns.eq(currentPage-1).addClass("active");
}

nextPage = () => {
 return currentPage===pagesCount ? null : changePage(++currentPage);
 
}

prevPage = () => {
 return currentPage===1 ? null : changePage(--currentPage);
}

document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37 :
   prevPage(); break;
  case 39 :
   nextPage(); break;
   }
}

$("#prev_btn").click(prevPage);
$("#next_btn").click(nextPage);
```

```css
#pages {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#pages .page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#pages .page:nth-child(even) {
  background: #008000;
}
#pages .page:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #00f;
}
#pages .page.toLeft {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#pages .page.toRight {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}
#pages .page h2 {
  color: #fff;
}
nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
}
nav input {
  background-color: #66cdaa;
}
nav #btn-group input {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav #btn-group input.active {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pages"></div>

<nav>
 <input  class="btn active-btn" type="button" id="prev_btn"  value="Prev.">

 <div id="btn-group"></div>

 <input  class="btn butt active-btn" type="button" id="next_btn" value="Next">
</nav>
```

One could also imagine a solution where all the pages would be in a line, forming a ribbon, and the pagination buttons would just translate the whole ribbon to the right place, to show the correct page `transform : translateX(n%)`

I hope it helps.